# Function-valued functions in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, orthonormal

I'm trying to prove the problem below:

Let $\Omega = (\omega_{ij})$ be a skew-symmetric $3×3$ matrix, i.e., $\Omega^T=-\Omega$.

Let $e_1(s)$, $e_2(s)$ and $e_3(s)$ be smooth vector-valued functions of a parametre $s$ satisfying the differential equations $\frac{d}{ds}e_i=\sum^3_{k=1} \omega_{ik} e_k$, where $i=1,2,3$.

Suppose that for some parametre value $s_0$, the vectors $e_1(s_0)$, $e_2(s_0)$ and $e_3(s_0)$ are orthonormal.

**Show that the vectors $e_1(s)$, $e_2(s)$ and $e_3(s)$ are orthonormal for all $s$.**

=

But what I have been doing is just expanding out the differential equations $\frac{d}{ds}e_i$ and translating the condition of "orthonormal" for $e_1(s_0)$, $e_2(s_0)$ and $e_3(s_0)$.

I have also defined a function $f_{ik}(s)=e_i(s) \cdot e_k(s)$, where $i,k=1,2,3$, and found its derivative by the product rule: $\frac{d}{ds}f_{ik}(s)=\frac{d}{ds}e_i(s) \cdot e_k(s) + e_i(s) \cdot \frac{d}{ds}e_k(s)$.

Any ideas on how to carrying on this proof? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to learn more about similar equations, a fantastic resource is the book by Murray, Li and Sastry on "A Mathematical Introduction to
Robotic Manipulation" https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf

Comment: Thanks heaps would look into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the set of differential equations as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\begin{pmatrix} e_1(s) & e_2(s) & e_3(s) \end{pmatrix} = \Omega \begin{pmatrix} e_1(s) & e_2(s) & e_3(s) \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with the solution
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} e_1(s) & e_2(s) & e_3(s) \end{pmatrix} &= e^{\Omega s}\begin{pmatrix} e_1(s_0) & e_2(s_0) & e_3(s_0) \end{pmatrix}\\
&= e^{-\Omega^{\top} s}\begin{pmatrix} e_1(s_0) & e_2(s_0) & e_3(s_0) \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
It turns out that $e^{\Omega s}$ is a rotation matrix (formally you can look into the [special orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#Lie_algebra)), which means that for any $s$ the frame $\begin{pmatrix} e_1(s_0) & e_2(s_0) & e_3(s_0) \end{pmatrix}$ is rotated, which preserves relative orientation, e.g. pick up a box, you can rotate it all day long, the sides remain fixed with respect to each other.